# Django Python With Gspread: 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples

Tags: python, django, list, django-models, gspread

I am trying to do something that I have never seen done before with django, I am trying to make a model field(`path_choices`) that shows all of the unique `path_names` from my google sheet in a choice box so that the user can select one of them. However when I tried to make my choices CharField I am getting the error:

```
ERRORS:

dashboard.Robot.path_choices: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
```

Right now the google sheet that I am trying to pull from with gspread only has two path-names, so if anybody has any idea on what is causing this problem or what I can do better with this, the help would be appreciated!
My Code (UPDATED CODE):

```py
from django.db import models

class Robot(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status_choices = [('driving', 'driving'), ('waiting', 'waiting'), ('stuck', 'stuck')]
    status = models.CharField(choices=status_choices, max_length=7, default='waiting')
    path_choices = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

My Form:

```py
from django import forms
from django import forms
from .models import Robot
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

class RobotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def _generate_choices():
        scope = ["REDACTED",'REDACTED',"REDACTED","REDACTED"]
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("dashboard/Files/creds.json", scope)
        client = gspread.authorize(creds)
        sheet = client.open("tutorial").sheet1
        path_name_fetch =  sheet.col_values(1)
        path_names = []
        temp_list = []
        path_options = []
        for i in path_name_fetch:
            if i not in path_names:
                path_names.append(i)
        for path_name_options in path_names:
            temp_list.append(f'{path_name_options}')
            temp_list.append(f'{path_name_options}')
            path_options.append(tuple(temp_list))
        
    path_choices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=_generate_choices())
    class Meta:
        model = Robot
        fields = {'path_choices'}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't from gspread(perhaps not fetching properly etc)?

Comment: @Garberchov, that is not the problem because I have tested this code in just a straight python file and it has worked without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do may not be in line with the intended use of `Choices`. Whenever the possibilities of a `Choice` change at the `Model` level, new migrations must be made.

Your implementation of `Choice` for `Robot.status` is static and in line with the example in the [Django documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#field-choices)

If instead you wanted to use a dynamic `Choice` for your `path_choices` that is retrieved from Google Sheets, I would recommend doing this in the [ModelForm using a `ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).
According to the documentation, the available choices can come from a callable, which would be your `path_options` wrapped in a function. `path_options` should then become a `CharField` without choices, since you manage those in the submission, rather than at the model level.

Models.py

```
class Robot(models.Model):
    ...
    path_choices = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

[ModelForms.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm)

```
class RobotForm(ModelForm):
      def _generate_choices():
            # Query GSpread
            choices = [('choice','choice'), ...]
            return choices

      path_choices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=_generate_choices())
      class Meta:
            model = Robot
            fields = ['path_choices', ...]
```

Comment: I am really confused by what you mean in this, in how `path_options` would become wrapped in a function but also become a `char_field` Do you have an example of this besides that documentation as that example doesn't seem as well sell suited to this use?

Comment: A `CharField` does not have any restrictions on the content that is saved aside from being a string of characters, you limit the inputs by defining `choices`. By moving the logic away from the model, and into the modelform, you can dynamically change the choices that are submitted to the path_options.

Comment: I am still confused as I am already using a `CharField`, is there a documentation or example that you can show that shows this more clearly?

Comment: I've updated my answer with examples. I have limited experience with ModelForms, but this is the gist of what I mean. The key difference is that a ChoiceField in a Form (and ModelForm) can be dynamic: "If the argument is a callable, it is **evaluated each time the field’s form is initialized**, in addition to during rendering. Defaults to an empty list."

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that makes much more sense as I didn't sink in that the model form would be a separate file. Will give it a shot

Comment: I assumed you were already using ModelForms to expose your Model to the user through a web interface, either way I hope this helps and do let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: It didn't work, I got the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`, I think it is a problem with the form but I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: There is no drop down box on the image, I don't know what I did wrong? https://imgur.com/a/ihPqKLZ

Comment: This is probably because the underlying model has a `CharField` instead of a `ChoiceField`. Have you tried explicitly defining the HTML Widget that should be created in the ModelForm? `path_choices = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=_generate_choices())`